# make css animation smoothly loop forever

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to make my CSS animation look snappier. I want it to loop forever and do so smoothly. The last frame should look like the first frame but right now, when the animation finishes, it SNAPS back to the original state. I want to use this effect form my custom slider.

Here is my code:

```css
.move {
  animation: move 30s ease;
  -ms-animation: move 30s ease; 
  -webkit-animation: move 30s ease; 
  -moz-animation: move 30s ease;
}


@keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom top;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom top;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom top;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom top;
    transform-origin: bottom top;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -o-transform: scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `animation-iteration-count` to `infinite` to make it run forever, then use the  `animation-direction` property to `alternate`, which plays the animation forwards, ten backwards. Here's the shorthand properties;

```
-ms-animation: move 30s ease infinite alternate; 
-webkit-animation: move 30s ease infinite alternate; 
-moz-animation: move 30s ease infinite alternate;
```

Credits: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), which has more information on how animations work.